# Groupby agg with join not produce the expected output

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe as below

```
   Wash_Month  Wash_Day
0           3         2
1           4         3
```

And the expected out put is

```
#d={'Wash_Month':'Wash_Month/Wash_Day','Wash_Day':'Wash_Month/Wash_Day'}

#df.T.astype(str).groupby(d).agg(','.join)
Out[329]: 
                       0    1
Wash_Month/Wash_Day  3,2  4,3
```

As you saw , I first do the transpose `T`.

If we `groupby` with `axis=1` and remove the `T`, I expected the same out put.

```
df.astype(str).groupby(d,axis=1).agg(','.join)
Out[330]: 
   Wash_Month/Wash_Day
0  Wash_Month,Wash_Day
1  Wash_Month,Wash_Day
```

The out put is mismatched with expected output . Is there specific problem on`agg` with `join` with `groupby` of `axis=1`

Since other `agg` function like `sum` work as normal

```
df.astype(str).groupby({'Wash_Month':'Wash_Month/Wash_Day','Wash_Day':'Wash_Month/Wash_Day'}, axis=1).sum()
Out[332]: 
   Wash_Month/Wash_Day
0                 32.0 # str 3 + str 2
1                 43.0
```

About why the result become float rather than a str check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751465/how-to-add-string-numbers-in-pandas)

Appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hint:

```
def f(x):
    print(x)
    print(type(x))
    return 1

df.astype(str).groupby(d,axis=1).agg(f)
```

Output:

```
  Wash_Month Wash_Day
0          3        2
1          4        3
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Note the output is a dataframe.

As opposed to:

```
def f(x):
    print(x)
    print(type(x))
    return 1

df.T.astype(str).groupby(d).agg(f)
```

Output:

```
Wash_Month    3
Wash_Day      2
Name: 0, dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Wash_Month    4
Wash_Day      3
Name: 1, dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Which f gets called with each series, hence 'join' is concatenating the column headers.

I can't explain it with digging through the source code, but it appears that the groupby along with astype(str) is causing agg to act differently in each situation.

Comment: Maybe one of the pandas Gods here can add more insight.

Comment: @Wen Awww schucks.... No, demigod maybe.... Well "pandas minion" is a better fit.  Thanks.